# Avoiding negative values in Forecasting

Tags: forecasting, boxcox-transformation

I have questions about the Box-Cox transformation that can be used to maintain positive forecasts (Log-Transform) when $\lambda=0$

\begin{equation}
  w_t  =
    \begin{cases}
      \log(y_t) & \text{if $\lambda=0$};  \\
      (\text{sign}(y_t)|y_t|^\lambda-1)/\lambda & \text{otherwise}.
    \end{cases}
    \tag{3.1}
\end{equation}

And the Back-transformation When $\lambda=0$:

\begin{equation}
\tag{5.2}
  y_{t} =
    \begin{cases}
      \exp(w_{t}) & \text{if $\lambda=0$};\\
      \text{sign}(\lambda w_t+1)|\lambda w_t+1|^{1/\lambda} & \text{otherwise}.
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

From my experience in some cases applying the log-transformation on historical data causes the MSE of the back-transformed fitted values to increase significantly, am I safe to assume that applying a bias adjustment will solve this problem?

This is the formula for the back-transformation using bias-adjustment:

\begin{equation}
\tag{5.3}
\hat{y}_{T+h|T} =
  \begin{cases}
     \exp(\hat{w}_{T+h|T})\left[1 + \frac{\sigma_h^2}{2}\right] & \text{if $\lambda=0$;}\\
     (\lambda \hat{w}_{T+h|T}+1)^{1/\lambda}\left[1 + \frac{\sigma_h^2(1-\lambda)}{2(\lambda \hat{w}_{T+h|T}+1)^{2}}\right] & \text{otherwise;}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

How is the variance $\sigma_h^2$ calculated for the hth step forecast?

Comment: This question is ambiguous, Rashad, because it seems to say that applying a "bias adjustment" is both a problem and will solve that problem.  Could you state specifically what you mean by "bias adjustment" and provide some context or a simple example to help us understand what you are asking?

Comment: Do you mean something like a $\log(y+1)$ transformation when you have some $y=0?$

Comment: (1) This is not a Box-Cox transformation: it is separate B-C transformations of the positive and negative parts.  (2) This is not what ordinarily would be called a "bias adjustment:" it's a formula derived from matching moments in lognormal distributions.  How the variance $\sigma_h^2$ is *estimated* depends on how you are performing the forecast.

Comment: Why not just set all your negative forecasts to zero?  You retain the better MSE, improve it in fact if all the actuals are non-negative, and avoid the negative forecast problem.

Comment: @jbowman I thought something similar, if a point forecast is negative I can set all consecutive point forecasts to the last non-negative point forecast, but if the first point forecast is negative I set all point forecasts to zero.

Comment: @whuber the source of these equations is Robert Hyndman’s book “Forecasting Principles and Practice 3rd edition” the book refers to this transformation as a type of Box-Cox Transformation where lambda = 0, what if one was using the ARIMA model how can we then calculate the h step variance ?